# Activity to behave as bottomsheet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-xml, androidx

I am implementing bottom sheet behavior in an activity. I don't want to implement the bottom sheet, instead I want my activity to behave as bottomsheet.
There are articles which is saying to set theme in manifest file, but it is not working same as bottomsheet.
I also want the slide down feature and when I touch outside activity to be hidden.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use fragment or bottomSheetDialogFragment.

Comment: I don't want to use fragment because I want one more bottomsheet in this activity.

Comment: To `Activity` to behave as `BottomSheet` you need to transition and Touch gesture . IMO this is not a good idea . instead of this you can have multiple BotoomSheets in Activity.

Comment: I will suggest either use transitions and theme with activity or you can use BottomSheetDialog , if you do not want to use BottomSheetDialogFragment. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: We can also use layout_behaviour to make any viewgroup inside coordinator layout to act as bottomsheet right ?